# Chromium disappears from the launcher when minimised

Tags: 11.10, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. When I minimise the Chromium browser window, the icon does not appear in the launcher. Instead it simply disappears. It had a video running, so I could still hear the audio from it. So where does the window minimise to? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around for you. Use Super-W to navigate to it. I have the same problem with eclipse and it works. alt-tab does not work so they are not equivalent....

If someone has a better *real* solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: is there any way instead of "super-W" key to navigate to the browser