# Chromium disappears when minimized

Tags: browser, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chromium disappears from the launcher when minimised](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79413/chromium-disappears-from-the-launcher-when-minimised)

I use Ubuntu 11.10. When I use chromium and minimise the window, the window does not appear in the tray. Instead it simply disappears, but it had a video running, so I could still hear the audio from it. So where does the window minimise to? Is this a known bug?

Comment: try alt-tab shortcut

Comment: i did... but it does not show it!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Desktop Environment you're using. Ubuntu 11.10 by default comes with Unity. If you are using Unity then go to the top left corner for the side panel to appear. You should see your Chromium icon there.